# different proxy_cache_min_use value for different status codes

Tags: nginx

Is there a way we can proxy cache 404 errors after 3 numbers and all other responses immediately?

As you can see, we can use `proxy_cache_valid` for different status code

```
proxy_cache_valid 200 302 10m;
proxy_cache_valid 404      1m;
```

Like the above, I also want to use `proxy_cache_min_uses` for different status codes with different values.

Edit:

I have only one location

```
location /
{
....
proxy_cache_valid 200 302 3600m;
proxy_cache_valid 404      60m;
proxy_cache_min_uses 3;
....
}
```

In the above example, all the status codes will be cached only after 3 usages. Where as I want only 404 to be cached after 3 usages and all other status code immediately.

Comment: Please be more specific what you want to solve with an example because `proxy_cache_min_uses number; Default: proxy_cache_min_uses 1; Context: http, server, location` it vary on where you want to use it

Comment: I understand the syntax of proxy_cache_min_uses is proxy_cache_min_uses number. But I want to have two different proxy_cache_min_uses for different status codes but on the same locaiton.

Comment: it might be possible in if then else but if is evil on nginx

Comment: it is not possible to use proxy_cache_min_uses with in the if else, any idea how to get it done?